# How to search and replace phrase in eclipse/regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace, wildcard

I am attempting to find and replace in eclipse the phrase

`doSomething(*,` with

`doSomething(*)`

(Where * is a wildcard)

I've tried both ctrl+f and ctrl+h. When I use a wildcard, it will find the phrase, but then when it is replaced, it will be replaced with literally, the asterisk, not the phrase that was inside of it. Is there a method to do so (maybe with regular expressions?). If there is not a way in eclipse, is there any software that will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `Regular expressions` checkbox when you hit `CTRL + F`.

```
Find: (doSomething\([^,]+),
Replace: $1)
```

Use `$n` in replace where n is the `n`th occurrence of a capture group `( )`

Answer (score 2):

`ctrl-f` and checked the `Regular expressions` option,

Find: `(doSomething\([^,]*),`

Replace with: `\1)`